# Setting "Customer" field on Line level of PO

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to set the "Customer" field on the Line level of a Purchase Order when I create the PO via script. I want the value to be the Job from the related Sales order. If you go into the UI to edit this field, you can enter both Jobs and Customers (the field is of type entity which is why both work).

My code is After Record Submit (User Event). Here is a snippet of the code:

```
var objcurrentSO = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', nlapiGetRecordId());
var ijob = objcurrentSO.getFieldValue('job');
nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "JOB ID", "Job: "+ijob);
//get line Item information from SO and store into arrlines array
var objPO = nlapiCreateRecord('purchaseorder');
//set header fields for objPo
    for (var j = 0; j < arrlines.length; j++) 
        {
            objPO.selectNewLineItem('item');
            objPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', arrlines[j].Item);
            objPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'description', arrlines[j].Description);
            objPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'rate', arrlines[j].Itemcost);
            objPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', arrlines[j].Itemquantity);        
            objPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'department', 71);
            objPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'class', arrlines[j].Class);
            objPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'location', ilocation);
            objPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'customer', ijob); //project set on line level
            objPO.commitLineItem('item');
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Setting PO line values', "Line: " + j + "; Item: " + arrlines[j].Itemtext + "; Itemcost: " + arrlines[j].Itemcost + "; Itemdescription: " + arrlines[j].Description);
        }
```

//submit the PO

With all of this what currently happens is the PO creates, but the Customer field is not set at all. My Log Execution shows the correct Job ID I am expecting. I can manually add the Job in the UI.

Any ideas?

Comment: One thing that's frustrating about this is that your post implies your code works at all. The setCurrentLineItem idiom is supposed to be for client scripts and records loaded/created in dynamic mode.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the "special order" or "drop ship" functionality so that the PO is generated automatically?

Comment: One thing that pops to mind, without being able to ask for more code/config is that the customer subsidiary isn't matching the subsidiary on the Purchase Order?

Comment: @bknights My code does work currently as is. The reason I can't use Special Order or Drop Ship is that this is for Services and only to be done under certain conditions. In other words, not every time this item is on an SO should it become a PO.

Comment: @LezYeoh - So that isn't the case. When creating the PO, the Vendor I set is definitely the same subsidiary as the original SO. I also can grab the Customer ID and set that successfully(did it for testing).

Comment: I'm just saying it shouldn't work. It's the wrong code for the context. Generally when you update multiple columns with the dynamic mode code you need to make the update synchronous or strange things happen. If you want to keep that code you might want to try adding `,true, true);` as the final parameters to all your `setCurrentLineItemValue` calls. e.g. `objPO.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'customer', ijob, true, true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Please try to ensure that Vendor and customer must be in same subsidiary.

Could you please try to create purchase order in dynamic mode like - `var poRecord = nlapiCreateRecord('purchaseorder', {recordmode:'dynamic'})`

Comment: This worked. Because in dynamic mode, order does matter, I needed to reorder part of my script but now everything works and the job set. Thanks!